Реализация импорта laravel excel
Всех приветствую, хочу реализовать программу, где пользователь задает поля для импорта, после чего из excel-файла извлекаются эти поля и их данные.
Хотелось бы послушать ваши идеи/предложения, как осуществить такую задумку на laravel.
Спасибо!)

Так а каких предложений Вы ожидаете? И чем конкретно по-вашему будет отличаться реализация на Laravel от реализации на чем-то другом, помимо возможно библиотеки для работы с Excel и самого фреймворка?

Я бы хотел услышать, идеи, как можно сделать динамическое добавление полей, которые можно было бы импортировать.  На данный момент времени есть программа, где строго заданы поля, которые должны быть импортированы

Ну наверное следует определить какие поля есть в документе и давать пользователю возможность выбрать определенные поля и потом использовать их для импорта.

Неплохое решение использовать laravel-excel поизучайте документацию
Если кратко:
Для каждого файла создаете файл в app/Imports/MyImport.php
можно создать для модели через терминал php artisan make:import UsersImport --model=User
после, просто вызываете функцию импорта
Excel::import(new UsersImport, 'users.xlsx')

